# BinomialBlurImageFilter apply kernel to image

Tags: c++, image-processing, itk

Is it possible to apply a custom 3x3 kernel to the `BinomialBlurImageFilter()` function? I always see the term `repitions`. In python or c it's quite easy to apply a custom 3x3 kernel, but in c++ I have no clue if it is possible or not.

> Example kernel (3x3): 
>   1 2 1 
>   2 4 2 
>   1 2 1

I've created a `BinomialBlurImageFilter` with the following line of code:

```
typedef itk::BinomialBlurImageFilter<InputImageType, OutputImageType> BinomialFilterType;
BinomialFilterType::Pointer blurFilter = BinomialFilterType::New();
blurFilter->SetInput(inputImage);
// here I want to apply a custom 3x3 kernel
OutputImageType::Pointer binomImage = blurFilter->GetOutput();
```

The documentation doesn't help me either [Documentation](https://itk.org/Doxygen/html/classitk_1_1BinomialBlurImageFilter.html). I've found an example with a kernel but I didn't get the concept of applying the kernel [Example](https://itk.org/Doxygen/html/SphinxExamples_2src_2Filtering_2Smoothing_2BlurringAnImageUsingABinomialKernel_2Code_8cxx-example.html#_a1). I'm a total c++ beginner, but maybe someone of you could explain it to me in a understandable way.

Thank you very much.

Comment: If you can do it in C, you can do it in C++ in exactly the same way.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing `blurFilter->Update();`

If `BinomialBlurImageFilter` does not already implement what you want, you might want to examine [`ConvolutionImageFilter`](https://itk.org/Doxygen/html/classitk_1_1ConvolutionImageFilter.html).